# Rendering 3D points with THREE.Points

Tags: three.js

Basically, I want to take a model, create a point cloud of the model and have the models move around. I could populate the models and move them around on the CPU, but I want to find a way to handle the animation on the GPU instead.

So I was thinking of using a `THREE.Points` object and associating a mesh with each point. I know you can associate a sprite with each point in a `THREE.Points` object, as seen in this example:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=point#webgl_points_sprites

Is there a way to associate a mesh (namely, an imported model) with each point, so that I can animate the vertices (and thus, the models) on the GPU with a vertex shader?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. You should look into the [`THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferGeometry)